# SQL Server 2008 Reporting Service 2008 the page margins not set while exporting to Excel

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

While using new SQL Server 2008 Reporting Service, the page margins that I specify in `Report Properties` > `Page Setup` do not seem to flow through to Excel when exported?
They always seem to be set to `Top & Bottom: 2.5cm`, `Left & Right: 1.9cm`, no matter what I set them to in the report.

This was working perfect in 2005 version.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have had a similar problem with PDFs. When I set the page to landscape in the Business Intelligence Studio it still renders as portrait in Acrobat

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you have also set the Interactive Size property to match the values you provide above.

Hope this helps,

Bill

Comment: Still the same problem after setting the Interactive Size property.

In MS support sites and some forums I found that this feature is currently not supported in Reporting Service 2008.

Any idea?